# Must a homeomorphism map empty set to empty set?

Tags: general-topology

Given $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a homeomorphism, and X a Hausdorff space. To show Y is also Hausdorff, I need to check $\forall x,y\in X, \exists \text{ open } U,V :x\in U,y\in V, U\cap V=\emptyset$; then $f(U)\cap f(V)=f(U\cap V)=f(\emptyset)=?\emptyset$.
I'm confused about the last equality because I can make up a homeomorphism where $f(\emptyset) \neq \emptyset$ as follows: take indiscrete topology $\tau$ on X, $f(\emptyset)=X, f(X)=\emptyset$. It's continuous from both sides, and bijective, thus a homeomorphism.
I guess the fact that X is Hausdorff precludes such possibilities, but don't know how to prove it. Could anyone give some suggestion?

Comment: $f$ is a map from $X$ to $Y$, not from power set of $X$ to power set of $Y$. Recall that $f(A)$is defined as $\{f(x): x \in A\}$. Any function maps  the empty set to the empty set.

Comment: Homeomorphism must be **bijection**.

Comment: That maybe could be correct in point-free topology, but when $f:X\to Y$ is actual function on sets and not some abstract morphism then $f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a topological space is a pair $(X,\mathcal{O})$ with $\mathcal{O}\subseteq 2^X$. satisfying some conditions and a (continous) map $f:X \to Y$ is a map of sets (satisfying some more conditions). So in the described equality there is no topology involved at all, but it holds simply due to basic set theory.